# URL Rewrites not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

On my website I am trying to rewrite a long URL to a SEO friendly one.

I've got the following code, but it doesnt seem to affect anything! However if I type `dgadgdfsg` into my htaccess, it throws an internal server error. So I am presuming it is something with Rewrite Rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /missing-people/user-profile.php?userID=$1&firstName=$2&lastName=$3 [L]
```

I have confirmed that mod_rewrite is on.

---

This is the current URL

http://mysite.com/missing-people/user-profile.php?userID=1&firstName=Liam&lastName=Gallagher

and this is what I want it too appear like

http://mysite.com/1/Liam/Gallagher

Comment: Could you please add a SEO Friendly URL you are trying to process? The external one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your RewriteRule to this (slightly modified from your version)

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ missing-people/user-profile.php?userID=$1&firstName=$2&lastName=$3 [QSA,L]
```

If that doesn't work try putting a `R` flag for testing purpose (which will make your browser change the original URI to: `/missing-people/user-profile.php?userID=1&firstName=Liam&lastName=Gallagher`

Answer (score 0):

Presuming your `userID` is comprised only of digits and `firstName` and `lastName` are only alphanumeric.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /(\d+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/ /missing-people/user-profile.php?userID=$1&firstName=$2&lastName=$3 [L]
```

A more strict version that does the same thing except it sets boundaries for the beginning and the end of the evaluated regex.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /^(\d+)\/(\w+)\/(\w+)$/ /missing-people/user-profile.php?userID=$1&firstName=$2&lastName=$3 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks @holodoc, hasnt worked however, nothing seems to happen

Comment: It should work. Try replacing `[L]` with `[R]` to see if a an external redirection would work or at least confirm that rewriting works (browser URL should change).